# Access to Notification center using Phonegap

Tags: ios5, cordova, nsnotificationcenter

Hello all,

Just wanted to know if there is a possibility to access the notification center using phonegap?

Thank You,
Suse

Comment: hello @suse, I need to access the notification center using phonegap. have u found solution?

Answer (score 1):

As like native apps you can access the Notification Center with either Local or Push Notifications once the use gave his permission.